# Avoid system.threading.threadabortexception error

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net desktop application and I am using thread.Abort() there.

I am getting system.threading.threadabortexception error.

Below is the error messagebox i am getting but not everytime.
Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click
Continue.....
Thread was being aborted.

Please suggest how to avoid this errormessage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please suggest how to avoid this error message.

The best, and correct, way to avoid this is to not call `Thread.Abort()`.  `Thread.Abort()` is really a bad idea in general.  Instead, you should build your routines around the [cooperative cancellation model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) built in the framework.

Comment: I understand Reed, but i have used Thread.Abort at only one place in my application. And the error message is also coming rarely. Is there any shorter approach or what happen if i remove thread.abort?

Comment: @user3060430 ThreadAbortException basically means "a thread was aborted" - if you call Thread.Abort, you need to expect this.  The right way to handle it is to fix that one place in your application where you're doing something inappropriate...

Comment: I am only aborting a running thread inside the closeing event of the form. I don't think it is necessary. Below is the code:          Private Sub frmFWCore_FormClosed(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
 Try
              t.Abort()
          
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogTraceInfo("CitiCSI - FWCORE_frm - FormClosed - error msg: ", ex.Message)
           
        End Try
 
 End Sub

Comment: @Anurag No way to know if it's necessary there or not, but if you don't abort it, it'll just run.. If it's a background thread, it'll shut down when the app shuts down, though.

Comment: I heard that if i use thread.IsBackground = true, then the thread will be automatically aborted after closing the application. Is it right?

Comment: @Anurag Yes.  Doing that will prevent the thread from keeping the application alive.

Comment: Thanks Reed. so i will remove thread.Abort() and set thread.IsBackground = true